# Combining certain columns from three excel files in one pandas DF based on the column number-Using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have three excel files that was read to pandas DFs, the tables are below :
DF1:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| F | G |
| M | K |

DF2:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| J | D |
| N | L |

DF3:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| J | E | Y |
| N | Q | V |
| J | D | B |
| E | B | F |

What I want to do is creating a fourth DF containing joined certain columns from the dataframes (Based on the column index) from the dataframes.
for DF4, what I want it to be :
1)(Column A from DF1) with (Column C from Df3) with (Column A from DF2)
2)(Column B from DF1) with (Column A from Df3) with (Column B from DF2)

The expected result of DF4 :

| Char 1 | CHAR2 |
| --- | --- |
| F | G |
| M | K |
| Y | J |
| V | N |
| B | J |
| F | E |
| J | D |
| N | L |

what I wrote for now :
`

```
import pandas as pd
NUR = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\jalal.hasain\Desktop\Copy of NUR Data 20-12.xlsx', 
                   sheet_name=['2G','3G','4G'])

DF1=NUR.get('2G')
DF2=NUR.get('3G')
DF3=NUR.get('4G')
```

`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with get columns in expected order in list for `DF3` with set columns names by [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
df = pd.concat([DF1, 
                DF3[['Column C','Column A']].set_axis(['Column A','Column B'], axis=1), 
                DF2], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
  Column A Column B
0        F        G
1        M        K
2        Y        J
3        V        N
4        B        J
5        F        E
6        J        D
7        N        L
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I got it and solved the issue, thanks again.